The 50 game between two players, selecting numbers between 1 and 10 inclusive + variations
Let's play a game with two players, with player 1 going first. The players take turns selecting a number between 1 and 10 inclusive. The person who says the number that makes the sum reach or exceed 50 wins. Who wins? Let's go backwards in increments of 11 from 50, we have 50, 39, 28, 17, 6. So player 1 selects 6 on the first turn and then always counters player 2 selecting $k$ with $11 - k$, hitting 50 and so winning the game for player 1. Pretty simple, right?
However, here are two variations on the game I came up which I'm wondering about.

What if players can't say a number so that its sum with the last number said is equal to 11? Which player then has the winning strategy?
What if both players can only use the numbers 1, 2, 4? Which player then has the winning strategy?


Do you know the general strategy for such games of classifying the "winning positions" and "losing positions"? For example, in the initial game but rephrased so that one starts at a number $n$ and subtracts until the total is $0$ or negative, every $n$ that is not a multiple of $11$ (including $50$) is a winning position. It's a good exercise to check that in game 2. (again rephrased to start at $n$ and subtract $1/2/4$ each turn), the losing positions are precisely $5,8,11,14,17,\dots50,\dots$.

Those two variations are different enough they should probably be different questions.

Here's a generic answer that works for all sorts of rules in this type of game
with two players, given that their moves are bounded by a constant.
Let $S = (X,M,k)$ where $n$ is the number of moves, $X$ is the player that made the last move, $M$ is the set of previous moves of the players that are used to determine if the state is possible, $k$ is the number being decreased towards $0$, then the set of all possible $S$ is the set of all possible states of the game. Notice since $k$ always decreases, and $k \leq 0$ means whoever made the last move is the winner, it is possible to determine the set of winning states for each player. The algorithm is as follows:

Let $n = \min k$. Marks each possible state with $k \leq 0$ as winning state for $X$ and losing state for the other player, all other possible states are unmarked.

For each player $P$, finds all states of their opponent $Q$ at  $k > n$ that allow $P$  to arrive at their winning states at   $k = n$. (If the game is symmetrical and the players can move indepedently i.e. $M = \{m_X\}$, then you can restrict to the "winning player"), mark these states as winning states for $P$/losing states for $Q$.

For each player $P$, mark their unmarked possible state after step 2 with $X = P$, $k = n+1$ as their winning state.

If $n\geq k_\text{initial}$, end the algorithm, otherwise, assign $n \leftarrow n+1$ and go to step 2


The second player is the winner if any of their winning states includes the initial $k$. Otherwise, the first player wins. Their strategy is to find a move that ends up at a state in their set of winning states.
Explanation of correctness: if the algorithm has correctly marked the states with for all $k \leq n$, it will correctly mark all the states with $k = n+1$. Step 2 is obviously correct. And it's doable, since the players' move are bounded and therefore the search space is finite. Step 3 can also be done in finite time, and it's correct because if the player $P$ 's state is unmarked, it means that every moves $Q$ makes will end up in a winning state for $P$, therefore it's a winning state for $P$.
You can then apply the algorithm for each problem:
Problem 1: The state is $S=(P,\{m_P,m_Q\},k)$ where $m_P.m_Q$ are the last number that $P,Q$ said. The rules for a possible state are:

$1 \leq m_P, m_Q \leq 10$
$m_P + m_Q \neq 11$
$k + m_P > 0$

Problem 2: The state is $S=(P,\{m_P\},k)$. The rules for a possible state are:

$m_P \in\{1,2,4\}$
$k + m_P > 0$

Here's a Python program for the second problem:
# The array containing the states. 0 means unmarked, 1 is winning, -1 is losing
# we increases the size of the array to account for related states that are out of bound
N = 50+5
s = [0 for k in range(N+4)]
moves = [1,2,4]
for i in range(4):
    s[i] = 1

for n in range(N+3):
    # step 2
    if s[n] == 1:
        for i in moves:
            if (n+i <= N) and (n+i > 3):
                s[n+i] = -1                
    #step 3
    if s[n+1] == 0:
        s[n+1] = 1
        
# get winning states
W = [i-3 for i,v in enumerate(s) if v == 1 and i <= N]
print(W)

The result is [-3, -2, -1, 0, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20, 23, 26, 29, 32, 35, 38, 41, 44, 47, 50]
We can see that the formula for winning state is $k \in \{-3,-2,-1,0\}\cup \{3l-1\mid l \in \mathbb{N}, k\geq 2\}$. One can easily prove that this is true.
In this case $k = 50$ is in the set of winning states so the second player wins

I think I have solved the first case. But the second case maybe doesn't have any such algorithm.
In the first case of your questions, I don't think following a single pattern suffices. You'll have to avoid the number $39$. If you reach $39$, your opponent will simply just add $1$, and then it's game over because you can't win as you can't add $10$ anymore. Thus, $38$ is the optimum number for you. Let's go back depreciating $12$ from $50$,i.e. $38,26,14,2$.
This strategy would only work if you start the game:-
You start with $2$. If your opponent says any number between $2$ to $10$, which say is $k$, you just hit then with $12-k$. But if you're opponent says $1$, you must say $1$ in order to make it $4$. Your opponent will not be able to add $10$ to make $14$, even if he knows the algorithm, because that will make the sum of the previous term and his term to be $11$. Hence he will be bound to say a value from $1$ to $9$ and you'll be good to go by using the $12-k$ part.
For the second case, the optimum number for you is $45$. But I can't generate a specific algorithm because of the lack of 3 in the series. Any help or hint will be very nice of the readers.

We shall follow Greg Martin's comment,
who already answered the question about the second variation. For the first variation, let a nonstarting position has the form (the current number, the last said number). Then going from the current number equal to $50$ downwards, it is easy to check that the losing positions are exactly:
$(40,1)$, $(39,10)$,
$(38,k)$ for any $k\in \{1,\dots,10\}$, $(37,10)$, $(36,9)$, $(35,8)$, $(34,7)$, $(33,6)$, $(32,5)$, $(31,4)$, $(30,3)$, $(28,1)$,
$(26,k)$ for any $k\in \{1,\dots,10\}$, $(25,10)$, $(24,9)$, $(23,8)$, $(22,7)$, $(21,6)$, $(20,5)$, $(19,4)$, $(18,3)$, $(17,2)$, $(16,1)$,
$(14,k)$ for any $k\in \{1,\dots,10\}$, $(13,10)$, $(12,9)$, $(11,8)$, $(10,7)$, $(9,6)$, $(8,5)$, $(7,4)$, $(6,3)$, $(5,2)$, $(4,1)$,
$(2,1)$.
